# Как использовать Template в Android Studio 4.1 Beta и Canary?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle, шаблоны

Как использовать Template в Android Studio 4.1 Beta и Canary???
Раньше можно было добавлять в папку plugin/lib/templates/other.
Сейчас этих папок нет, при создании студия не реагирует. Потому что все стягивается с Android.jar файла

Если кто не понимает о чем идет речь, то об этом https://habr.com/ru/post/274959/

Как быть теперь???? кто - нибудь уже нашел способ как юзать свои кастомные проекты. Типо MVP, MVVM, CLEAN и прочее. Так как ручками каждый раз создавать базовые вещи это утомительно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61138322/where-are-the-file-templates-in-android-studio-4-1-located) говорят, что гугл будет использовать другое апи для Template.
Так же там есть пример [плагина](https://github.com/thagikura/AndroidTemplatePluginSample).